# Add ServiceStack Reference SSL error

Tags: servicestack

I try to add a service stack reference in my project but I getting this error

[image]

could ignore the certificate? thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]I accepted the certificate in add service reference, then add the servicestack reference and work!

Comment: Does the issue come back after a restart of Visual Studio?

Comment: My guess would be the default VS Add Service Reference is storing your answer to trust the server you've provided and upon restart that is no longer known and you get prompted for it again. I'm working on updating the extension to handle this issue in a similar way, for now I would use the work around you've described above and I'll update this SO question once the extension is updated.

Comment: Are you able to hit the 'WMSvc-FENIX-DEV-2' server via the host name instead of the IP address? If you could try the Add ServiceStack Reference using the host name it will probably work ok.

Comment: I've updated the ServiceStackVS extension to work around this issue. Could you please test the latest version (available here https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStackVS/raw/master/src/ServiceStackVS.vsix) and let me know if you have the same problem or not?

Comment: cool, worked for me, thank you, I think you should apply the patch to "Update ServiceStack Reference" in contextual menu option too

Comment: Updated again to include fix for update. Let me know if you have any problems and I'll update here when the new version is available from the VS gallery :). You'll have to manually uninstall and reinstall the addin this time as the version numbers will be the same. https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStackVS/raw/master/src/ServiceStackVS.vsix

Comment: Hi @Layoric now I am getting the error "The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized" because I added basic authentication to my services, Do you have some tip how Can I add servicestack reference with basic authentication.

Comment: can you give me some more info about how `basic authentication` was added? Was it at the IIS level or ServiceStack `BasicAuthProvider`? Are you in an intranet environment?

Comment: yes is basic authentication with IIS level and I'm in an intranet environment, thank you

Comment: Currently SSVS doesn't suppport add/update reference for servers that require authentication. Best option for now would be to simple copy the code by browsing directly to the appropriate language path.
https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Add-ServiceStack-Reference#language-paths

You could also suggest this as a feature on the ServiceStack Uservoice site.
https://servicestack.uservoice.com/forums/176786-feature-requests